# MySQL grab row only if it's the latest ID that also matches a string (location_is)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a query where I want rows that are `In Stock` only if they have the highest ID. (As lower ID's of the same set of mac addresses for example, are historic records)

The version of MySQL I am using is `4.0.24`

```
+----------------+-------------+-----+
| mac_address_is | location_is | id  |
+----------------+-------------+-----+
| 00xxF7         | In Stock    | 185 |
| 00xxF7         | Out         | 186 |
| 00xx6A         | In Stock    | 200 |
| 00xx6A         | In Stock    | 201 |
```

I would like these results: `00xx6A` as it's the only one `In Stock` as the max ID.

The `In Stock` for `00xxF7` should be disregarded as it's not the latest (highest id for that mac) in the location `In Stock`.

EDIT:
I can't use sub-queries due to the version of the software. `4.0.24`

Also, I don't think I can use `limit` as my query will have to return about a thousand entries. It's a thousand entries of latest `mac_address_is` that `= "In Stock'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order your table by id descendingly, filter for in stock and limit the records to 1 in the output:

```
select * from yourtable
where location_is='In Stock'
order by id desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
SELECT mac_address_is FROM yourtable 
WHERE location_is="In Stock"
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.mac_address_is, MAX(t.id) as id
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.location_is = 'In Stock'
 GROUP BY t.mac_address_is;
```

Comment: This would list 00xxF7 as well, and the OP was clear it did not want that value to be listed.